# Questions on representing data types in C using printf

Tags: c, printf

I have a couple of examples of playing with floats, and doubles via `printf` in C that I think exhibit some strange / unintuitive behavior, and for each example I want to know

1. Is my interpretation correct? (or have I made some bug in the code or my reasoning) and
2. *If* my interpretation is correct, what is the reason for having the code behave in this way?

I am using C99 on a Windows 10 machine. I will try to avoid just making type-checking complaints =p

A) According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format), the max positive value for single precision variables is 2^127. However, overflow doesn't occur for floats until we reach over 2^128 - why is this? Is C on my computer somehow not using the IEEE standard?

```
float f;

// no overflow
f = 3.4e38;  // ~ 2^128
printf("\n b10 val: %e, hex val: %x, n bytes: %i", f, f, sizeof(f));

// overflow once we get past 2^128
f = 3.5e38;
printf("\n b10 val: %e, hex val: %x, n bytes: %i", f, f, sizeof(f));

> b10 val: 3.400000e+038, hex val: c0000000, n bytes: 4
> b10 val: 1.#INF00e+000, hex val: 00000000, n bytes: 4
```

B) I cannot print long doubles on my machine (they just appear as overflowed doubles), even though I believe I am using the correct format spec `%Le`, and the long doubles are properly represented as 16-byte (according to `sizeof`). Am I doing something wrong?

```
long double d_l;
  
d_l = pow(2, 1024);
printf("\n b10 val: %Le, hex val: %llx, n bytes: %i", d_l, d_l, sizeof(d_l));

d_l = 2;
printf("\n b10 val: %Le, hex val: %llx, n bytes: %i", d_l, d_l, sizeof(d_l));

> b10 val: 3.172897e-317, hex val: 61fdf0, n bytes: 16
> b10 val: 3.172897e-317, hex val: 61fdf0, n bytes: 16
```

Comment: The float maxvalue is around 3.40282347E+38... so just what you calculated

Comment: Try using `%a` to print the values in hex. If this doesn't work your C implementation is outdated.

Comment: In your second example, try calling `powl()` instead of just `pow()`.

Comment: In contrast to Wikipedia and comments and answers entered so far, the maximum value representable in a `float` is not near 2^128. It is ∞. 2^128 is merely the end of the finite range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted code has multiple problems:

- `f = 3.4e38;`  You convert a floating point literal of type `double` to type `float`, you should probably write `f = 3.4e38F;` or `f = powf(2, 127);`
- `printf("\n b10 val: %e, hex val: %x, n bytes: %i", f, f, sizeof(f));` multiple problems here:

  - you pass a `float`, which is actually converted to a `double` and passed as such but `printf` expects an `unsigned int` for `%x`: This has undefined behavior. The output is meaningless.
  - you pass the value of `sizeof(f)`, which has type `size_t`, but `printf` expects an `int` for `%i`: This has undefined behavior, but unlikely to cause problems.
- `f = 3.5e38;` this is a conversion of a literal of type `double` to a `float`, but in this case the value of the `double` exceeds the range of type `float`. This has undefined behavior. It seems to produce `INF` but this is not guaranteed by the C Standard. If you wrote `f = 3.5e38F;` the compiler would probably detect the overflow as the literal exceeds the range of its defined type.
- `printf("\n b10 val: %e, hex val: %x, n bytes: %i", f, f, sizeof(f));` same problems as above
- `d_l = pow(2, 1024);` the computation is performed as `double`. You should probably instead use the function `powl` to compute as `long double`.
- `printf("\n b10 val: %Le, hex val: %llx, n bytes: %i", d_l, d_l, sizeof(d_l));` same problems as above. Passing a `long double` for `%llx` has undefined behavior.
- `d_l = 2;` no problem here!
- `printf("\n b10 val: %Le, hex val: %llx, n bytes: %i", d_l, d_l, sizeof(d_l));` see above.

You cannot really draw any conclusions from the output, the behavior is undefined for multiple reasons.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char *tohex(char *buf, const void *val, size_t n) {
    // convert to hex in little endian format
    char *p = buf;
    const unsigned char *src = val;
    while (n --> 0) {
        p += sprintf(p, "%02X", src[n]);
    }
    return buf;
}

int main() {
    char buf[33];
    float f;
    double d;
    long double d_l;

    // no overflow
    f = 3.4e38;  // ~ 2^128
    printf("b10 val: %E, %A, hex val: %s, n bytes: %i\n",
           f, f, tohex(buf, &f, sizeof(f)), (int)sizeof(f));

    // overflow once we get past 2^128
    f = 3.5e38;
    printf("b10 val: %E, %A, hex val: %s, n bytes: %i\n",
           f, f, tohex(buf, &f, sizeof(f)), (int)sizeof(f));

    d = 3.4e38;  // ~ 2^128
    printf("b10 val: %E, %A, hex val: %s, n bytes: %i\n",
           d, d, tohex(buf, &d, sizeof(d)), (int)sizeof(d));

    d = 3.5e38;
    printf("b10 val: %E, %A, hex val: %s, n bytes: %i\n",
           d, d, tohex(buf, &d, sizeof(d)), (int)sizeof(d));

    d_l = powl(2, 1024);
    printf("b10 val: %LE, %LA, hex val: %s, n bytes: %i\n",
           d_l, d_l, tohex(buf, &d_l, sizeof(d_l)), (int)sizeof(d_l));

    d_l = 2;
    printf("b10 val: %LE, %LA, hex val: %s, n bytes: %i\n",
           d_l, d_l, tohex(buf, &d_l, sizeof(d_l)), (int)sizeof(d_l));

    return 0;
}
```

Output for OS/X 64-bit:

```
b10 val: 3.400000E+38, 0X1.FF933CP+127, hex val: 7F7FC99E, n bytes: 4
b10 val: INF, INF, hex val: 7F800000, n bytes: 4
b10 val: 3.400000E+38, 0X1.FF933C78CDFADP+127, hex val: 47EFF933C78CDFAD, n bytes: 8
b10 val: 3.500000E+38, 0X1.074F8C4D3CD7BP+128, hex val: 47F074F8C4D3CD7B, n bytes: 8
b10 val: 1.797693E+308, 0X8P+1021, hex val: 00000001041843FF8000000000000000, n bytes: 16
b10 val: 2.000000E+00, 0X8P-2, hex val: 00000001041840008000000000000000, n bytes: 16
```

Output for OS/X 32-bit:

```
b10 val: 3.400000E+38, 0X1.FF933CP+127, hex val: 7F7FC99E, n bytes: 4
b10 val: INF, INF, hex val: 7F800000, n bytes: 4
b10 val: 3.400000E+38, 0X1.FF933C78CDFADP+127, hex val: 47EFF933C78CDFAD, n bytes: 8
b10 val: 3.500000E+38, 0X1.074F8C4D3CD7BP+128, hex val: 47F074F8C4D3CD7B, n bytes: 8
b10 val: 1.797693E+308, 0X8P+1021, hex val: BFF87978000043FF8000000000000000, n bytes: 16
b10 val: 2.000000E+00, 0X8P-2, hex val: BFF87978000040008000000000000000, n bytes: 16
```

The difference comes from the 48 padding bits in the `long double` representation: `long double` only has 80 bits on this architecture, the 48 bits in the high order bytes (12 hex digits) are meaningless.

Comment: Thanks for all this! Some follow-up questions:

1) Is converting a literal of type double to flloat the way in which I do it really a problem - I don't think it should affect anything?

2) If I use `sizeof` which returns `size_t`, what is the proper format spec for `printf` for `size_t`?

Answer (score 3):

Check out https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html.

If you look at the format of a float, the exponent goes from -127 to 127, as wikipedia is saying. However, the mantissa can go up very close to 2, thus allowing to represent numbers close to 2^128.

Comment: And this is also what the Wikipedia article linked by the OP says.

Comment: It is but an interactive example is worth a thousand pictures. And you know what they say about pictures.

Comment: Yes.  My point is that the OP has misinterpreted their source.

Answer (score 0):

Beware of [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). It depends on your CPU.

You could want to code:

```
 printf("\n b10 val: %Le, hex val: %llx, n bytes: %i", 
        d_l, *(long long*)(&d_l), sizeof(d_l));
```

Since you want to view your 64 bits `long double`  as a `long long`

Alternatively code:

```
union { long long ll; double long dd; } u;
memset (&u, 0, sizeof(u));
u.dd = d_l;
printf ("ll=%lld, dd=%Le\n", u.ll, u.dd);
```

Stricto sensu, this is probably [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Check by reading [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) website then some C standard (like [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) or something newer).